# Wrong conversion from struct to JSON by MATLAB

Tags: json, matlab

I want to communicate with a web server using the MATLAB's webwrite function. here is what I found problematic:

imagine a struct like this: **1x1 struct with 3 fields**

```
test1x1 = 

a: 'a'
b: 'b'
c: 'c'
```

pay attention that `test1x1` is a 1x1 struct with 3 fields

now I have another struct, lets call it `test1x2`, this one is a **1x2 struct with 3 fields**

```
test1x2 = 

1x2 struct array with fields:

a
b
c

>> test1x2(1)

ans = 

a: 'a'
b: 'b'
c: 'c'

>> test1x2(2)

ans = 

a: 'a2'
b: 'b2'
c: 'c2'
```

now I want to sent `test1x1` as JSON to my webserver

```
response = webwrite('aURL',test1x1 , weboptions('MediaType','application/json'));
```

if you use the debugger, somewhere in the `webwrite` function you can see the pure JSON which will be sent to server, here is the generated JSON:

```
{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c"}
```

and now , `test1x2` will generate the following JSON:

```
[{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c"},{"a":"a2","b":"b2","c":"c2"}]
```

now here is the problem, in the webserver, the interpretation of the JSON generated from `test1x1` is that it has 3 entries, each 1 field. because MATLAB does not add `[]` in front and at the end of the generated JSON for a 1x1 struct.

the interpretation of the generated JSON from `test1x2` is correct and as expected: 2 entries, each 3 fields

---

Now, don't you think that the generated JSON of a 1x1 struct is wrong?

Comment: Conversion to cell arrays as per the accepted answer is a good workaround but it's worth noting that interpreting MATLAB's scalar output as 3 objects with 1 field each is absolutely not a correct interpretation of the JSON by the web service. `{}` and `[]` have fundamentally different meanings and if they aren't treated as such then this may not be the last problem you run into with this web service.

Comment: @Will well the web service uses a JAVA library for iterating over JSON. I think the package name is `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`.

Comment: Is the code auto generated on the server? Or is the problem that you have no control of it? Because it seems as if the problem is that the server implementation does not support scalars. If possible you may want to change things there so that it can handle scalar input and convert it to what format it needs. Otherwise the java equivalent to a struct would be a class with no methods and all public members (or possibly private members with getters and setters, depending how opinion). This does not seem to be violated in `text1x1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a little ambiguity here: Matlab does not have the concept of a "one element array", Matlab treat such entities as scalars. Thus, you want to convert `[struct('a','a','b','b','c','c')]` (a list with single struct element) to json, but what matlab sees is `struct('a','a','b','b','c','c')` (a scalar struct element).
I suppose you can workaround it by forcing scalars to be items in a cell array: `{struct('a','a','b','b','c','c')}`.

Comment: well thanks, it works fine! but only for 1x1 structs, so first I have to check and only if the struct is 1x1, add the additional {}. for the rest, no {} is needed

Comment: @behzad you might consider converting all your arrays to cell-array and then you will not have this conflict.

Comment: well converting to cell array will have a big domino effect, code base is huge :D i prefer the old if/then for this @Shai

Comment: You don't have to convert to cell array in your workspace, just replace `test` with `mat2cell(test,ones(size(test)))` on the way into `webwrite`...